# Setting mod rewrite in htaccess / all images lost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This seem to be an often question online, but most site's have old answers and or way out of date methods.

I'm using .htaccess to rewrite URLs for an SEO website.

Basically, the header links go like this:

```
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="index/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="softwares/" title="Softwares">Softwares</a></li>
        <li><a href="about/" title="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact/" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

So the full url would be: http://localhost.com/softwares/ or http://localhost.com/about/ and etc...

> RewriteRule   ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [NC]

Now, this works for when routing the /$/ to the file, however, all images, href, and etc don't work / show.  (because the url is technically pointing to a sub directory).

My question: What should we write or what should we do to fix those images, css, urls, and etc...

Answer (score 0):

The “problem” here is that you’re using relative paths that are resolved differently on base paths with multiple segments:

```
 base path  | reference   | resolved path
------------+-------------+--------------------
 /          | img/foo.png | /img/foo.png
 /index.php | img/foo.png | /img/foo.png
 /index/    | img/foo.png | /index/img/foo.png
```

One simle way to solve this is using absolute paths instead:

```
 base path  | reference    | resolved path
------------+--------------+---------------
 /          | /img/foo.png | /img/foo.png
 /index.php | /img/foo.png | /img/foo.png
 /index/    | /img/foo.png | /img/foo.png
```

You can also change the base URL using the [`BASE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) element. But note that this will affect *all* relative URLs.

Comment: If I were to use absolute paths, I'd have to rewrite all href's, correct?